# What's wrong with the switch?

Tags: java, android

I've got a function:

```
public void vfShareQuote (String textToShare){
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Also there is a lot programmatically created buttons, that's 2 of them:

```
Button agafon_1 = new Button(this);agafon_1.setText(R.string.agafon_1);llPreViewList.addView(agafon_1, lParams);
Button agafon_2 = new Button(this);agafon_2.setText(R.string.agafon_2);llPreViewList.addView(agafon_2, lParams);
```

Here is the OnClickListener:

```
OnClickListener oclShareQuote = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//Set the text based on the selected button and send it to function vfShareQuote
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.string.agafon_1:
        vfShareQuote(getResources().getText(R.string.name_agafon)+":\n"+getResources().getText(R.string.agafon_1));
        break;
    case R.string.agafon_2:
        vfShareQuote(getResources().getText(R.string.name_agafon)+":\n"+getResources().getText(R.string.agafon_2));
        break;
    }
    }
};
```

And of course:

```
agafon_1.setOnClickListener(oclShareQuote);
agafon_2.setOnClickListener(oclShareQuote);
```

**But when you press the button - nothing happens. Why? Or is it programmatically create buttons?
What to do?**
*Translated by google.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `R.string.agafon_1` and `R.string.agafon_2` are not the id. They are just the id of the string resource. Set id to the buttons and use them instead. use like

```
agafon_1.setId(id1);
agafon_2.setId(id2);
```

where id1 and id2 is two int . and use them

```
OnClickListener oclShareQuote = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//Set the text based on the selected button and send it to function vfShareQuote
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case id1:
        vfShareQuote(getResources().getText(R.string.name_agafon)+":\n"+getResources().getText(R.string.agafon_1));
        break;
    case id2:
        vfShareQuote(getResources().getText(R.string.name_agafon)+":\n"+getResources().getText(R.string.agafon_2));
        break;
    }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the switch block.. You have not setting Id for the Buttons and you are attempting to access them `onClick`..

try

```
agafon_1.setId(1);
agafon_2.setId(2);
```

and then use these id's in switch block

```
OnClickListener oclShareQuote = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//Set the text based on the selected button and send it to function vfShareQuote
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case 1://agafon_1 is clicked
        vfShareQuote(getResources().getText(R.string.name_agafon)+":\n"+getResources().getText(R.string.agafon_1));
        break;
    case 2://agafon_2 is clicked
        vfShareQuote(getResources().getText(R.string.name_agafon)+":\n"+getResources().getText(R.string.agafon_2));
        break;
    }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating buttons programmatically you should supply an id for each button in such way :

```
agafon_1.setId("btn id");
```

and There is also an issue, For some android sdks switch cases is not working any more,
you have to make it with if statements.

Comment: I am curious, when did switch case not working issue was raised, I/We never faced this kind of issue..

Comment: I can't remember exactly the version of sdk i was working with when i received such a warning that switch case is not available for this version of android.
May be eclipse was kidding me, but i had to change all switch cases to if conditions.
I think i was working with version 4.2.2